# Using one query for multiple manipulations

Tags: laravel-4

For avoiding a query to execute repeatedly, I changed the below code:

**First block**

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user = User::find($user->id);
$notifications = $user->notifications()->take(10); // Once query runs here
$count = $user->notifications()->whereSeen(0)->count(); // there's a call for a second execution here
$total = $notifications->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

To this:

**Second block**

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user = User::find($user->id);
$query = $user->notifications()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
$notifications = $query->take(10);
$count = $query->whereSeen(0)->count();
$total = $query->get();
```

Well the first outputs correctly but in the second `$count` always return `int(0)` and `$total` won't contain any thing. What's going wrong?

***Update***

start\global.php:

```
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user = User::find($user->id);
    $notifications = $user->notifications()->take(10); // Once query runs here
    $count = $user->notifications()->whereSeen(0)->count(); // there's a call for a second execution here
    $total = $notifications->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
    if($notifications)
    {
        $msg = array(
            'comment'   => 'A comment was posted.',
            .
            .
            .
        );

        $nots = array();
        $new = $total->each(function($not) use ($msg, &$nots)
        {
            $text = $msg[$not->type];
            $link = url('dashboard/project/view/'.$not->project_id);

            if(!in_array($not->type, array('suggest', 'comment', 'ok', 'notok', 'confirm', 'pre')))
            {
                $text = str_replace(":nick", $not->project->user->nick, $text);
            }
            $nots[] = '<a href="'.$link.'" class="item"'.($not->seen == 0 ? ' style="background-color: #EBF3EF;"' : '').'><i class="icon-signin"></i>'.$text.'<span class="time"><i class="icon-time" title="'.date('m/d', strtotime($not->created_at)).'"></i></span></a>';
        });
    }
    .
    .
    .
    View::share('notifications', $nots);
```

View:

```
@if($notifications)
     @foreach($notifications as $not)
     {{ $not }}
     @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with this:

```
// Assuming you use eloquent user provider
$user = Auth::user(); // 1st query for user
$user = User::find($user->id); // 2nd query for user
```

instead:

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

Then:

```
$notifications = $user->notifications()->take(10); // Once query runs here
```

no, it does not. Your query is executed here (with `count()`):

```
$count = $user->notifications()->whereSeen(0)->count();
```

---

Now, your 2nd code block does this:

```
// $query has orderBy
$query = $user->notifications()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');

// $query has limit(10)
$notifications = $query->take(10);

// $query has where clause
$count = $query->whereSeen(0)->count();

// $query still has all of the above
$total = $query->get();
```

So, if `count()` returns `0`, then obviously `get()` will return empty collection too.

The only difference in those codeblocks is `whereSeen(0)` which is not present in 1st `get` query.

However there can't be any difference in those `count`s, unless you query another user.

Comment: Hmmm But I use `$notifications` to display last 10 items, in which there maybe a row with `seen=1` column is existed.

Comment: I don't get your point here. You run `$query->count(); $query->get()`. It's the same query builder instance.

Comment: I mean it executes at `take(10)` actually. As @marcanuy answered, `whereSeen(0)` applies only to the previous 10 items.

Comment: Like I said, `take` doesn't execute the query. It only applies `LIMIT 10` clause on it.

Comment: Then I shouldn't be able to use a `foreach` loop on `$notifications` to display last ten notifications!

Comment: I don't see any foreach here, so I won't be trying to guess what else you have there... Either show whole code or trust me it does not run any query with `take()`

Comment: I've unseen notifications stored in `$count` and then using `$total` to go through all last tens, if they are seen already, then highlight it for user. I'm going to do this approach as my failed (second) code block.

Comment: Not going to go through your code now, but one thing: `if ($notifications)` returns true, always. It's a collection object. Instead use `if (count($notifications))`. And, you don't pass `$notifications` to the view, but something that is processed in that code blcok `$nots`, so you rather not run foreach on it.

Comment: Sorry, yes I was mistaken about `foreach`. But yet the part I'm dealing with is fetching last 10 notifications, then have a number of unseen ones then highlight the seen notifications through a simple if block. In the second block `$count` is always zero, however based on what you said and execution on `count` method it should work as well. So the question is why?

Answer (score 0):

Method *whereSeen(0)* applies only to the previous 10 items, so it seems that none of those 10 items matches that condition and this gives count=0.

When *$query->get()* executes, $query has already been executed when *->count()* was called.

Comment: What's the difference between first block `$count` and second block `$count`?